# Child div expanding outside parent div

Tags: html, css

Hi and thanks for your help,
Some how my child divs are breaking outside my parent div

[image]

css:

```
        #itembody{
        min-height: 120%;
        width: 75%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 10px #888888;
//child div
    #itemdiv{
        font-family: century gothic;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        border-style: outset;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: gray;
    }
```

How can I fix it so that my parent div gets the same height as my child div.

Comment: can you please explain what u want and what u r getting as its nt clear with the image u posted

Comment: This looks like an issue of floated elements in parents. You should use `clearfix` for this

Comment: did u mean that child contents are floating out side the parent div border??

Comment: Yes sorry, I thought it was obvious by reading the title.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your 2 children elements are floated. You'll have to apply a clearfix to the parent div.

You can find examples and a good explanation of clear fixes here:
http://code-tricks.com/css-clearfix-methods/

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle, I'll take a look and help you figure it out.

Comment: I don't know if I can js fiddle it it's a huge website with a huge mysql db.

Comment: Just pull out the little bit of html and css that goes with it :)

Comment: Can you also add a little bit about how the html structure is?